# How to permanently monitor events in exchange folders with a Java thread via managed J-EWS

Tags: java, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ewsjavaapi

I will be using managed EWS for Java to create a thread that performs tasks on our Exchange server as reactions to creation, modification and deletion of elements in certain folders for certain users.

I have a few questions regarding EWS:

1. `StreamingSubscriptionConnection` can only be kept open for a maximum of 30 minutes.
   What is the correct solution to practically keep it open permanently?
   Close and reconnect every 29 minutes?
2. After calling `connection.open()`, the thread that called it continues and would end. Currently I use an infinite `Thread.Sleep()` after `connection.open()` to keep the thread alive. What is the correct solution to keep the main thread alive?
3. What happens if a thread having an open connection crashes?
   Will the connection on the exchange server stay open for the remaining timeout time?
   Is it safe to assume that a new connection created right after a crash will receive all subscribed events (or will it go to the old connection only?)?
   On the Exchange Server, how do I see how many EWS subscription connections are active?
4. Is a new thread created every time a `CreationDelegates` is used? As in is it automatically multi-threaded?

It's an Exchange 2013 server.